# Copy a specific key value set of HashMap into another

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to get a values of a specific key of a HashMap and then copy that into a new one. Is there a way to achieve this than what I tried? Thanks in advance!

```
LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> TradeDetailsNewOrPrevious = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> temp = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

temp = (LinkedHashMap<String, java.util.List<String>>) TradeDetailsModified.get(tradeID);

TradeDetailsNewOrPrevious = (LinkedHashMap<String, java.util.List<String>>) temp.clone();
```

I get "ClassCastException:

> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap"

in the line `"temp = (LinkedHashMap<String, java.util.List<String>>) TradeDetailsModified.get(tradeID);`"

Comment: `TradeDetailsModified.get(tradeID);` returns a `List<String>` not a `LinkedHashMap<String, java.util.List<String>>`

Comment: BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. variable names should start with lower case character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't reflect your question, What I understood - you need the values of a specific key or a set of keys and then you want to copy those values into a new one, This is what I tried, you can update this one with a loop:

```
      LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> tradeDetailsNewOrPrevious = new LinkedHashMap<>();

  //    taking some values for a clear understanding
  tradeDetailsNewOrPrevious.put("AA", Arrays.asList("a", "aa", "aaa"));
  tradeDetailsNewOrPrevious.put("BB", Arrays.asList("b", "bb", "bbb"));
  tradeDetailsNewOrPrevious.put("CC", Arrays.asList("c", "cc", "ccc"));

  LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> temp = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

  List<String> tradeIDs = Arrays.asList("AA", "CC", "DD");

  for (String tradeID : tradeIDs)
  {
     if (tradeDetailsNewOrPrevious.keySet().contains(tradeID))
     {
        temp.put(tradeID, tradeDetailsNewOrPrevious.get(tradeID));
     }
  }
```

**It will copy all the values with the keys matched with tradeIDs.**

If this isn't what you are looking for, make the question clear in a comment.